# how to retrieve text of buttons clicked in windows form with one single method

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a windows form application with multiple buttons. I need to retrieve the text property of any button clicked in order to create a query to the database. the only way I know is to create a button click event and cast the sender as button then do a switch case for each button Id which seems very hectic since I probably will have more than 100 buttons in the entire application. So my question is there a generic key press method I can create which can retrieve the text property of any button pressed/clicked on the form? Please excuse me if the question is not very clear. Any help will be appreciate

Comment: If you able to cast sender as Button then you can easily access control.Text property right?? why you needed switch which is unnecessary according to me

Comment: I have the same question. Why can you not do ((Button)sender).Text to retrieve the text ? Why do you need the switch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single click event handler for all similar kind of buttons. This way there will be click event subscribed for every button but only one method which will be executed for all buttons. You can determine which button was pressed as follows.
Using sender object as follows;

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;
        //Query using buttonText
    }
```

**Update:**
Above answer will still require you to subscribe click event for each button. If you don't want that then have a look at following approach;

You could use ([ClickTransparentButton](http://textuploader.com/58cnu) or) disable `(Enabled=false)`  all these buttons and add click event on parent Form. Once you get click event you can get button which was clicked as follows;

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var p = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
  var control = GetChildAtPoint(p);

  if(control is Button)
  {
     var buttonText = ((Button)control).Text;
     //Query using buttonText
  }
}
```

But this has few disadvantages such as, you will not be able to operate these buttons using keyboard.
and more...

Comment: Hi there thanx for the prompt answer. but the above code u have suggested will still require me to write a line of code for each button to attach to this event if i understand correctly. or is there a single method or line of code which can attach all the buttons to this custom handler?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create some function as buttons click handler:

   ```
   private void buttonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)  
   {  
       string buttonName = (sender as Button).Text;  
   }
   ```

2A. Connect *Click* event of every button to this handler.

2B. To automate connection of button click handler use something like that:

```
private void connectButtonsHandlers()
{
    foreach(var c in this.Controls)
    {
        if(c is Button)
        {
            (c as Button).Click += buttonClickHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Add this code to form constructor to perform connection at program start.

Comment: so it means I still will need to write a code for each button to connect to this handler right? but I am looking for a method which can subscribe all the buttons to this event handler? is that possible?